# Symmetric group elements with centralizer subgroups contained in alternating subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n,A_n$ denote the symmetric and alternating groups each on $n$ letters respectively. Let $\sigma \in S_n. $ I attempted to arrive at a handy equivalence condition for the statement

> $$C_{S_n}(\sigma)\cap A_n=C_{S_n}(\sigma).\tag{$P$}$$

I found that this statement

> $$\sigma\; \text{ fixes at most one letter and the cycle decomposition of } \sigma\; \text{does not contain any }\tau \notin A_n\tag{$Q$}$$

is a necessary condition for $(P)$.

I could not make progress in proving/disproving that the statement $(Q)$ is also sufficient for $(P)$.

Any help in this direction is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: [Please don't delete then repost like this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4304359/104041)

Comment: @Shaun The initial question had serious mistakes. I had edited it but I was afraid the question might have been misinterpreted. Would you like me to let the edit stay and delete this one? Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess. Just be careful in future . . .

Comment: You can ask for advice on the meta site.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you for previous edits and instructions. I shall do as suggested.

Comment: @Shaun It would be nice if you provided a link to the Mathematics Meta site next time, since the author of this question [posted their meta question on the global Meta Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371814/serious-mistakes-in-question-and-deletion-in-case-of-no-answers-comments), where it's not a good fit. You can do so using the text `[meta]` in comments: it produces [meta].

Comment: Thank you, @gparyani

Comment: Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: The condition (Q) is not sufficient. For example $\sigma=(123)(456)\in S_6$ commutes with the permutation $(14)(25)(36)\notin A_6$.

Comment: @kabenyuk thank you very much. Can (Q) be strengthened (in a useful way) to be sufficient?

Comment: We must presumably also assume that the lengths of all cycles are pairwise different.

Comment: @kabenyuk Thanks again. I found it to be sufficient.